# Why is my state being updated here?

Tags: reactjs

I'm pretty new to React, but liking it so far.  I'm building a large application, which is going well, except I've run into an issue.  I'm building a list of responses to questions, and they can be deleted, but I also want to have a "Cancel" button so all unsaved changes can be reverted.  What is confusing me is the cancel button reverts to the initial state for the name value, but not the responses.  If I add in some console logging to the response deletion script, I would expect to see log lines 1 & 2 match, with 3 being different.  However, I'm seeing that 1 is the original, but 2 & 3 match.  Why is state being updated before I call setState, and why does updating state seem to update the my initial props?

EDIT: I added a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/44671/)

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    name: this.props.question.name,
    responses: this.props.question.responses,
  };
},
handleCancelButtonClick: function(e) {
    this.replaceState(this.getInitialState());
},
handleNameChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({name: e.target.value});
},
handleResponseDeletion: function(e) {
    var resp = this.state.responses;
    var from = Number(e.target.value);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.responses));
    resp.splice(from, 1);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.responses));
    this.setState({responses: resp});
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.state.responses));
},
render: function() {
    var key = "mp" + this.props.question.name;
    var resp = [];
    if (this.state.responses) {
        this.state.responses.forEach(function(response, i) {
            var rkey = "r_" + this.props.question.name + "_" + i;
            resp.push(<ModalResponse response={response} key={rkey} value={i} deleteResponse={this.handleResponseDeletion} />);
                }.bind(this));
        }
        return (
            <layer id={this.props.question.name} style={questionModal} key={key}>
                <h2>Edit {this.state.name}</h2>
                <button onClick={this.handleCancelButtonClick}>Cancel</button>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label for='client_name' style={formLabel}>Question Name:</label><br />
                    <input type='text' style={formControl} id='question_name' name='question_name' value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleNameChange} required />
                </div>
                <div class='form-group'>
                    <label  style={formLabel}>Responses:</label><br />
                    <ul style={responseList} type="response_list" value={this.props.qname}>                       
                        {resp}
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </layer>                            
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `splice` modifies original array. It means the one that belongs to the original `question`. So when you call `getInitialState` from within `handleCancelButtonClick` you get modified array.

To avoid this you need to somehow clone original data inside `getInitialState`. For example

```
getInitialState: function() {
  //copy array and responses
  const copy = resp => ({...resp})

  return {
    name: this.props.question.name,
    responses: this.props.question.responses.map(copy)
  };
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Yury.  I couldn't quite figure out your code, but I wasn't aware that splice would modify back to the original question.  I ended up removing splice and just doing a forEach on the array and pushing to a new array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did to fix the issue:

```
handleResponseDeletion: function(e) {
  var resp = []
  var from = Number(e.target.value);
  this.state.responses.forEach(function(res, i) {
    if (i != from) {
        resp.push(res);
    }
  });
  this.setState({responses: resp});
},
```